# Is the adjoint matrix $A^*$ defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A=(a)$ be a $(1\times 1)$-matrix with entry  in an arbitrary commutative ring with identity, is the adjoint matrix $A^*$ defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic $1\times 1$ matrix over a commutative ring $R$, the adjugate (or adjoint) matrix is $I=(1)$, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). Complex conjugation does not make sense in $R$, so the notation $A^*$ is not the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint
$A. Adj(A)=Adj(A).A= Det(A) I$

Comment: I think you're talking about what's usually called the [*adjugate* matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).  OP is asking about the [adjoint matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_matrix).

Comment: I am sorry. I misunderstood with adjoint matrix.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I think the only reasonable interpretation is that the question is about the adjugate (which is sometimes also called the adjoint, as stated on the Wiki page you linked to). After all, what would complex conjugation even *mean* in an arbitrary commutative ring?

Comment: @HansLundmark: I was thinking of *adjoint* as *tranpose* with respect to a generalized inner non-degenerate inner product.  But you could be right.  I think we need more information from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the adjoint (better called the *transpose*) of $A$ is itself when viewed as a matrix. To put this into context, for $R$ commutative let $M$ be an $R$-module that is isomorphic to $R^n$. Then we can talk about linear maps $M \rightarrow M$, and since modules isomorphic to $R^n$ can be written in terms of a basis (dimension is unique), then those linear maps can be represented by square matrices with $R$-valued entries.

The adjoint of $A: M \rightarrow M$ is a map $A^{\ast}: M^{\ast} \rightarrow M^{\ast}$, where $M^{\ast} = Hom(M, R)$, defined by $(A^{\ast} h)(m) = h(Am)$ for every $h \in M^{\ast}$ and $m \in M$.

A $1 \times 1$ matrix whose sole entry is $a$ thus represents the map $m \mapsto am$. Then $h(Am) = h(am) = (ah)(m)$, so $A^{\ast}$ multiplies the homomorphism $h$ by the element $a$. Therefore $A^{\ast}$ and $A$ have the same matrix representation.